# Disable third party overlays in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, directx, overlay

My (C#) XNA Game application uses WPF to get input from the user, this works fine, but my program is unstable when other applications like TeamSpeak puts an overlay on top of my game.

All of my WPF objects gets a bit “choppy”, and after a while `game.Run()` in `Main(Program.cs)` throws an  error:

> *AccessViolationException - Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.*

Is there an easy way to prevent overlays from hooking up to my XNA application?

Edit: (More info to clarify)
This only happens when I use WPF with XNA, if I only run XNA there is no problems at all. The application runs in window mode, so it’s a bit annoying that overlays hooks up to it anyway.
I have used a tutorial at C#Corner for the implementation:
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/iersoy/windows-controls-and-wpf-usercontrols-inside-an-xna-game-project/

I´m pretty sure it is the `[STAThread]` part over `static void Main(string[] args)` that makes the TeamSpeak overlay collide with WPF.

Comment: Does this happen in regular XNA games, without WPF? And, how are you using WPF? Can you provide code or a link to the relevant tutorial/library?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I provided a bit more info in the text. I think it would solve the problem if I just could prevent the overlay from hooking up. I guess this might happen with other overlays as well.

Comment: It's sounds like you possible are accessing memory from your STAThread on another thread. The STAThread attribute ensures certain memory requirements that go with using DirectX or WPF. I will have a look on how you implemented this when i have some spare time.

Comment: That is real nice of you. I´m sure there is a way around this, but it is currently over my head. Since the application works just fine when there is no external stuff injecting code I´m more than happy with a solutions that denies it from happening. There might be a way to change the protection level when starting the Main class?

Anyway, I did some more testing and WPF works just fine if I don’t use _spriteBatch.Draw(), but my application gets a bit boring without graphics :/ 
Windows forms seems to work fine too, even with spriteBatch.Draw(). But Forms isn’t really what I want to use.